# Server starts correctly in eclipse, but not in Intellij

Tags: spring, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am desperately trying to get my web application server to work right in IntelliJ. The rest of my team uses Eclipse and it works fine there, but when I start the server in IntelliJ, the server starts with no errors but I get 404s from SoapUI when hitting the endpoints.

First of all, we are using Tomcat 7, jdk 1.8, and Spring 3. I am aware of version incompatibilities between some of these, however we have workarounds for all of them and like I said, everything works in Eclipse, so there has to be something different about IntelliJ that causes the problem.

Any ideas are welcome, even if they are just vague hints. At this point, I'll take anything I can get. Here are the server logs for each. If there is anything else that I should include, please let me know.

I did have to trim the server logs slightly to get it to meet the char length restrictions, shortening package names and removing the log4j output (which is identical in both logs), as well as removing company and project specific identifiers.

Eclipse

```
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING: No rules found matching 'Server/Context/Resource'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING: No rules found matching 'Server/Context'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:...-war' did not find a matching property.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built: Mar 28 2017 16:01:48 UTC
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:  7.0.77.0
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name: Windows 7
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version: 6.1
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:   amd64
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version: 1.8.0_121-b13
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE: C:\Users\...\p4store\..._F40B034E3F1E7_5150\...\...-2017.04.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME: C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\...\p4store\..._F40B034E3F1E7_5150\...\...-2017.04.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\...\p4store\..._F40B034E3F1E7_5150\...\...-2017.04.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\endorsed
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -DCUT_APP_ENV=LOCAL
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk8/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk8/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk8/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Oracle64\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin;C:\Apache\Maven\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Eclipse\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.4.RELEASE;;.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 940 ms
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/GlobalNamingResources/Resource'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/GlobalNamingResources'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:08 PM catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:09 PM catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [328] milliseconds.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:09 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING: No rules found matching 'Context/GlobalNamingResources/Resource'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:09 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING: No rules found matching 'Context/GlobalNamingResources'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:09 PM catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\...\p4store\..._F40B034E3F1E7_5150\...\...-2017.04.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\...-war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:13 PM catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:13 PM catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
<log4j output/>
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:22 PM catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:26 PM catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet '...-rest'
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:58:27 PM catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18451 ms
```

IntelliJ

```
C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\bin\catalina.bat run
[2017-06-15 02:50:10,747] Artifact ...-war:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE: "C:\Users\...\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_...-2017_08_0"
Using CATALINA_HOME: "C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\temp"
Using JRE_HOME: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk8\jre"
Using CLASSPATH: "C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:11 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING: No rules found matching 'Server/Context/Resource'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:11 PM tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING: No rules found matching 'Server/Context'.
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built: Mar 28 2017 16:01:48 UTC
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number: 7.0.77.0
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name: Windows 7
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version: 6.1
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture: x86
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk8\jre
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version: 1.8.0_121-b13
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE: C:\Users\...\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_...-2017_08_0
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME: C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\...\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_...-2017_08_0\conf\logging.properties
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -DCUT_APP_ENV=LOCAL
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\endorsed
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\...\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_...-2017_08_0
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\temp
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk8\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Oracle64\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin;C:\Apache\Maven\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 458 ms
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 45 ms
[2017-06-15 02:50:12,335] Artifact ...-war:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Connected to server
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:12 PM catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\...\p4store\..._F40B034E3F1E7_5150\...\...-2017.08.0\...-war\target\...\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:15 PM catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
<log4j output/>
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\docs
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\docs has finished in 102 ms
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\examples
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\examples has finished in 431 ms
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\host-manager
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\host-manager has finished in 114 ms
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\manager
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 15, 2017 2:50:22 PM catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\manager has finished in 126 ms
[2017-06-15 02:50:26,625] Artifact ...-war:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-06-15 02:50:26,625] Artifact ...-war:war exploded: Deploy took 14,290 milliseconds
```

Comment: Did you configure the context correctly in the run/debug configuration, deployment tab? Do you open the URL with the correct context?

Comment: I'm using the same tomcat instance in both IDEs, same HTTP port, jdk, VM arguments, and war file. Am I missing anything? Also, when I test the endpoints, I'm using the same SoapUI project for both.

Comment: Check the context configuration as described above.

Comment: Do you mean the spring context? Yes, both IDEs are using exactly the same code, not a copy. The projects created in each are both using the same project path.

Comment: No, the [deployment context](http://i.imgur.com/Kfk4mSY.png).

Comment: That did it! I guess eclipse was setting the context root automatically while IntelliJ doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that IntelliJ IDEA is deploying the app under the same context as you would expect:

[image: context]